# ext4 file-system max inode limit - can anyone please explain?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4, inode

Recently we had a problem where one of the ext4 file-systems seemed unable to handle very large number of files, `more than 6mln in this case`, in spite of having enough space. Is it `6mln` the max number, an ext4 file-system can have when formatted with all the default settings? I tried to Google it but didn't get any definitive answer. Anyone one out here can shade some light on this please? Cheers!!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no default *as such* for ext4, it depends on the size of the device and the options chosen at creation.  You can check the existing limits using

```
tune2fs -l /path/to/device
```

For example,

```
root@xwing:~# tune2fs -l /dev/sda1
tune2fs 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /

[lots of stuff snipped]

Inode count:              1277952
Free inodes:              1069532
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512

[lots of stuff snipped]
```

As per `man mkfs.ext4`

> -i bytes-per-inode
>
> Specify the bytes/inode ratio.
> mke2fs creates an inode for every bytes-per-inode bytes of space on the disk.   The
> larger  the bytes-per-inode  ratio,  the  fewer inodes will be
> created.  This value generally shouldn't be smaller than the blocksize
> of the filesystem, since in that case more inodes would be made than
> can ever be used.  Be warned that it is not possible to expand the
> number of inodes on a filesystem after it is created, so be careful
> deciding the correct value for this parameter.

Answer (score 6):

It depends how you formatted the filesystem. Using `tune2fs -l <device>` you can find the number of inodes your device has, probably around 6 million inodes in your case. Every file or directory uses an inode.

As far as I know, the only possibility to increase the number of inodes is to re-format your filesystem. The `-i` parameter to the `mkfs` can be used to specify the bytes/inode ratio. The default value is defined in `/etc/mke2fs.conf` (on my system: 16384).

A larger bytes/inode ratio defines fewer inodes, a smaller one more inodes. The default values works well in most cases, but if you have a large number of small files, you may run into the limit and may need to format the filesystem with a smaller bytes/inode ratio.

Answer (score 1):

The explanations the others have given is correct: Each file or folder in your system represents an **inode**.  There is a limit to how many inodes are in use.

Now, how can we work with this thing?

#### Check Your iNode Use

Use the command `df` with argument `-i`, that is: **`df -i`**.  For instance, I get:

```
Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            247945     421  247524    1% /dev
```

#### What's the Max iNodes I can get?

According to RedHat, you can have 4.3 billion iNodes on a volume.  To quote...

> ...the theoretical maximum number of inodes is equal to 2^32 (approximately 4.3 billion inodes)... [(Source: RedHat.com)](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/inodes-linux-filesystem#:%7E:text=There%20are%20many%20inodes%20on,of%20inodes%20on%20your%20system.)

#### Increase Your INode Limits

You'll need to reformat the volume entirely, so make sure to backup any data first.  And then, if you wanted, say, 200 million iNodes, just run...

```
mkfs.ext4 -N 200000000 /dev/you/want/reformatted
```

And on my 100GB volume, that gives me output like...

```
Creating filesystem with 26213616 4k blocks and 250037568 inodes
Filesystem UUID: ...
```